# Codeacademy - HTML, CSS excercise

Tags: html, css

I just started Code Academy and I'm doing a project where I create a mock website for myself. I completed the whole thing basically, however, there were a few steps that I couldn't submit. It just gives me the "Oops" alert. Firstly, it's step 5/21. The command is to create an empty style tag. I thought I did it correctly.

This is my code:

```
<style> 
</style> 
<h1> Valentina </h1> 
<p>Hi! I am learning how to make
my very own web page! I really don't care much about
blueberry muffins and long walks on
the beach.</p>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email">   
<input type="submit">
```

But Code Academy gives me Oops!, why?

Comment: `<style>` elements must be in the `<head>`

Comment: Can you add a link to the excercise

Answer (score 1):

All the answers you recieved might be the case.

**This code goes in the `<body>` section of the webpage:**

```
<h1> Valentina </h1> 
<p>Hi! I am learning how to make
my very own web page! I really don't care much about
blueberry muffins and long walks on
the beach.</p>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email">   
<input type="submit">
```

**Whislt the style tags goes inside the `<head>` section of the webpage.**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but a wild guess would be that your empty `<style></style>` should go in the `<head>` tag

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that they are expecting a ***complete style tag***

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

And even though style tag can go anywhere, it's maybe you need to try to put it in `<head>` tag

Answer (score -2):

Define Complete style tag

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

It wil work for you I guess.